# FourSquare API for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, foursquare

As I need to integrate the foursquare in my application,
I have found the API and also integrate in my application. But there is some problem.

I want to show the nearest venue around me. As there is also method to show the venue

```
+(void)searchVenuesNearByLatitude:(NSString*)lat
                    longitude:(NSString*)lon
                   accuracyLL:(NSString*)accuracyLL
                     altitude:(NSString*)altitude
                  accuracyAlt:(NSString*)accuracyAlt
                        query:(NSString*)query
                        limit:(NSString*)limit
                       intent:(NSString*)intent
                     callback:(Foursquare2Callback)callback;
```

But the problem is what are the parameter need to pass for search venue which are in area of 5 KM.
Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance,

kunal patel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andreas has made a good example iphone project that hosted on github
I tried it and it's working very well take a look at https://github.com/anka/bw_examples/tree/master/FoursquareIntegration

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

accuracyLL - this stands for accuracy Latitude Longitude.

Your foursquare library you'll see it's a wrapper for the foursquare API documented here:  https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html

llAcc is the location accuracy in meters. For 5Km you would use 5000.

Answer (score 0):

If you use oauth login method that would become more easy, You have to login through oauth 2.0 then using access token you can get any user details. I have found a very nice [tutorial](http://codegerms.com/login-with-foursquare-in-ios-objective-c-using-oauth-2-0/) related to oauth, I hope this would help you