# Use of FourSquare API to find nearby places in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, foursquare

How to use Foursquare API to find nearby places in iOS Applications.

As I am new in this environment.. So please help me to find any sample tutorial available on the API.

I had gone through [this link](https://github.com/anka/bw_examples/tree/master/FoursquareIntegration), And I got the response "error type" : deprecated so please provide another link for this same solution..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579327/four-square-api-for-iphone

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem. If so can you share some insights to your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try looking at [this link](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries) for more information about Objective-C libraries that work with the foursquare API.

**Edit:** Currently [this one](https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api) appears to be the more recent, more chances of it working properly, also good documentation there on how to integrate it. It is the second one listed in the foursquare library page.

Also check out the foursquare developer site in general, you will need to know the different endpoints and what data they return anyway => https://developer.foursquare.com/

Comment: Can't really help you if you do not say what the problem is, "crushing" not detailed enough, what error, which API endpoint, paste some code, etc..

Answer (score 2):

[this Link](https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api#register-for-an-api-consumer-key) is pretty good,comes with little instruction, u can use the search venues,check in,photo services..heaven!
go through [foursquare Api](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/) page for desired modification.
in the FSQMasterViewController.m file you need to **#define kClientID @"yourClientId"**
and **#define kCallbackURL @"ur callback url"**
fix your infoPlist the urlSchemes too